¿Por qué cuando pego algunas líneas de código en un archivo de Visual Studio Code se borran las primeras líneas de este mismo?
Tengo una clase en Java y en las primeras líneas tengo esto:
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

Y el en el resto del código, tengo varias funciones, si pego algo, sea una función completa, o un signo en cualquier parte del código, algunas de las primeras líneas del código se borran y quedan así:
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

Me está pasando esto varias veces:(

Debe ser alguna extensión que da formato automático al código. Debes poder desactivarlo aunque no tienes por qué preocuparte. import javax.swing.*; ya cubre el botón, el área de texto, el campo de texto, etc. Mira si esto te sirve https://stackoverflow.com/a/56972128/13419694

Hola Sarah, bienvenida, si escribes código en vez de pegar, sucede lo mismo?.

a simple ojo parece que el tienes una extencion que valida tu codigo y elimina los import innecesarios, por ejemplo borra este import java.util.regex.Pattern porque no es necesario si tienes import java.util.* ya que el asterisco importa todos lo que hay dentro de utils... y asi con los demas paquetes... el swing quiza lo borra porque no lo estas usando o porque ya otro paquete lo usa ...

Me parece que esto es un comportamiento normal de la IDE, las clases que importas individualmente:
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

Se eliminan automáticamente si hay un import general de estas clases, en este caso:
import javax.swing.*;

Si deseas desactivar esta acción ve a File > Preferences > Settings y busca "auto import", en Java puedes desactivar esta opción


VSCode elimina automáticamente los imports que no son usados.
Así que si en tu archivo no estás usando ninguna clase del paquete javax.swing.* (JButton, JTextField, JTextArea), el IDE los eliminará.
